# Tinymce won't initialize on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, tinymce

I have a tinymce editor in my application and everything works fine.
However, I discovered a bug on Safari.

Here's what happens:

I open the page once and everything works fin. I go to another page and then go back to the previous one. Now the tinymce isn't initialized. Instead, I see just a textarea, and these errors in console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'f.document.selection')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'j.createRange')
```

which happen in the tiny_mce.js file.

I found another user which had this problem:

```
http://lists.apple.com/archives/web-dev/2005/Jun/msg00146.html
```

But there isn't a solution provided. I'm stuck with this, does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Seems to work on the TinyMCE fiddle page in Safari, even when paging forward and back through the examples: http://fiddle.tinymce.com . Perhaps you could post some examples of your code?

Comment: Hey.. did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you're getting the tinymce lib isn't loading the moment you're calling the init fn. I highly speculate that your browser is loading the page from the cache (bfCache) which stops the event onLoad from running, in which you're script might be dependent on running that event first.

btw, I am working on a web application that operates heavily on tinymce v4 and it works very well in all browsers (Desktop and mobiles) so the bug your facing might be either a caching problem or a reordering the fns your calling. I would recommend you provide a reduced test case on Fiddle to debug that.